# Calculating Lines of Code metric for Svn repo ( lines added , lines modified , lines deleted)

Tags: svn, version-control, diff, metrics, diffstat

I want to generate a LOC(Lines of code) metric for my svn repo given a date range:

**Date:**   July 2012       
**Lines Added:**     38,719 
**Lines Modified:**  22391  
**Lines Deleted:**   9512
**Total:**  70621

I have explored tools like Statsvn, svnplot, fisheye, and tortoisesvn and they all provide LOC graphs but none show the level of detail I need (lines added , lines modified , lines deleted) and also , I need the raw data rather than a graph.

I have also looked around the web/other threads on this and none of the solutions(e.g. using svn diff or diffstat) seem to have the 3 elements (lines added , lines deleted , lines modified) that i need.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to get this data ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you please describe **why** you need such kind of stats? What's the use case for this? IMO it's kind of useless information unless you have some special case.

Comment: I know its a useless metric but I still need the information.

Comment: This answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7860151/1023562) claims it does just what you need: *I also tried to solve task such as "how many lines were removed, added or just changed in selected period of time". So I wrote simple shell script (for Linux only).*

Comment: Thanks for the responses